# Node middleware next() goes to error (JWT verification)

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

I set up `jsonwebtoken` in `node.js` and testing it with `postman`. First upon login I generate the token, then I copy it and use for the post request to a protected route. And `jwt.verify` runs just fine, the correct `userId` is retrieved, but when I call `next()` (see below) it goes to `404` error handler instead of the `index` where the protected routes are located:

```
var index = require('./routes/index')

function verifyToken (req, res, next) {
      // Get auth header value
      const bearerHeader = req.headers['authorization']
      // check if bearer is undefined
      const message = 'Unauthorized user, access denied!'
      if (typeof bearerHeader !== 'undefined') {
        const bearerToken = bearerHeader.split(' ')[1]
        jwt.verify(bearerToken, 'privateKey', (err, userData) => {
          if (err) {
            // Forbidden
            console.log(err)
            res.status(403).send({ err })
          } else {
            console.log(userData.userId)
            req.userId = userData.userId
 ------>    next()
          }
        })
      } else {
        // Forbidden
        res.status(403).send({ message })
        // res.sendStatus(403)
      }
    }

    // app.use('/auth', index);
    app.use('/auth', verifyToken, index)
```

Why is it happening? What am I doing wrong here? Basically my goal is to set `userId` on the `req` object, then get it back in the root route `auth/` in `index`

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: There is none really. Just my error handlers get called. And they have message `404`, nothing else, no info

Comment: seems like you are silently suppressing the error. Can you put loggers in your error handler to get the stacktrace?

Comment: Ok, I figure out that `POST` gives the error, but `GET` is working fine. I still do not get why...

Comment: Ok, will try doing that

Comment: If that is happening then its because your api point is defined for `get` rather than `post`.

Comment: Ok, I see, thank you!